# Jmeter: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, jmeter-5.0

When I'm running the test plan; I'm using a parameter for appurl

appurl: ${_P(appurl,xxx.abcabc.net)}

and it works fine with all HTTP request sampler and gets 200 as the response code.
But when I try to target any specific DNS name using

appurl: ${_P(appurl,ab12c1002032:8443)}

it gives me the following response:
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Malformed IPv6 address at index 9: https://[ab12c1002032].

One thing I notice is there are "[]" parentheses around DNS. It automatically appears in the URL.

Please help me correct this parentheses issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have anything but [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) or [DNS hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) in the Server Name or IP field of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

You need either to split it into `hostname` and `port` like:

```
${_P(appHost,xxx.abcabc.net)}
```

and

```
${_P(appPort,8443)}
```

[image]

or put your `appurl` property into the Path section of the HTTP Request sampler:

[image]

however in this case you might face malfunction of certain control elements like [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/) so I would recommend splitting the URL into hostname and port like in the first picture

Comment: Thanks for the insights. It works fine, rather than providing everthing in appurl, splitting  DNS hostname and Port makes sense and is logical.

Answer (score 0):

What i can understand from you description is that You should not be providing the port number in the url that is why it is stating malformed url.
Try to run it by providing the port number in port number box it should run successfully.

[image]